# How to update metadata of png/jpg/tif images using Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

Which possibility do I have to write meta data in the form of key-value strings into the file formats .jpg, .tif, .png using Java? In the best case I am looking for a uniform procedure using standard Java tools or a library. Is there a suitable library that can be used free of charge for commercial purposes or can I otherwise access the metadata to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pixymeta](https://github.com/dragon66/pixymeta) might be the library you are looking for. It is commercially usable and is free of charge. It's a successor of [iCafe](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe).

For example of the use of the iCafe library for writing to IPTC see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732994/13920601).

Answer (score 0):

It's supported by the standard Java API since at least Java 1.5 as far as I remember, use the package javax.imageio.metadata, especially [IIOMetadata](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata.html). There's an [example in the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/imageio/spec/apps.fm5.html). JPEG and PNG are fully supported, [TIFF requires at least Java 9](https://openjdk.org/jeps/262).